# Isolating Oracle related records by timestamp in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I apologize if this is duplicated from anything. I was struggling with proper wording of the problem.

The issue at hand involves the data table *LOG*.  Log's schema is:

```
USERID - Char(20) 
CODE - Number 
TIME - TimeStamp(6) 
COMMENT - CHAR(120)
```

This log is used to track user behavior within an application.  For the most part, all that is needed is the timestamp, but certain activities are being scrutinized and reporting has been requested.  In this case, the affected items are the open and close values for editing an account.  0 means Open, 1 means close. COMMENT, in this case, holds the account signature. Ex:

```
MYUSER | 0 | 12-DEC-2014 x.yy.zz | 776655-4
MYUSER | 7 | 12-DEC-2014 x.aa.bb | Did Stuff  
MYUSER | 1 | 12-DEC-2014 x.aa.cc | 776655-4
```

Expected scenarios are that the user may have more than one account open at one time, and that the user may or may not have closed an open account before a query is run on the table. Additionally, a user may close an account, then open it again later, creating multiple instances of open-close pairs with the same account number.   The only thing that cannot happen is that an account cannot be opened twice concurrently, not even by the same user (it is "locked for editing" and "checked out"). This also means, of course, that one user cannot close the account *for* the other user.

What I'm trying to do is provide the requested timespan.  While this will interface with an old .Net program, its .Net version is 1.1 (I know) and I'd prefer not to encourage the thought that we can keep editing 10 year old software instead of replacing it if I can avoid it.  This means using the PL/SQL solution of a stored procedure in a package.  I can easily compare the times of two records, but I'm having trouble putting together the PL/SQL to ensure that I get the timespans of each logical pair of open-close events.  Any suggestions?

Edit in response to comments:

The expected output would be each "event" and a duration, such as below.

```
USERID | <open_timestamp> => <close_timestamp> | duration (as hh.mm.ss.xxxxxx)
```

or

```
MYUSER | 14-NOV-2032 hh.mm.ss.dddd => 14-NOV-2032 hh.mm.ss.xxxx | rr.ee.ss.ult
```

The marker indicating the start and end time might be replaced by an identifying integer, but that doesn't really matter.  The real issue is getting the grouping between an open and a close to establish open-close events

Edit in response to first answer by MT0:

This is almost there, but unfortunately mishandles the closing events when an account is opened more than once, but not necessarily closed.  This is sample data in the table.

```
------OPENS-------
User   | Account| Account Open Time
MYUSER | 738056 | 16-DEC-15 08.14.27.239780000 AM 
MYUSER | 738152 | 16-DEC-15 08.06.07.702045000 AM 
MYUSER | 738056 | 16-DEC-15 07.47.28.825647000 AM 
MYUSER | 738152 | 16-DEC-15 07.44.11.168721000 AM 

------CLOSES---------
User   | Account| Account Closed Time             
MYUSER | 738056 | 16-DEC-15 08.14.49.313336000 AM 
MYUSER | 738152 | 16-DEC-15 08.06.05.657541000 AM 
MYUSER | 738056 | 16-DEC-15 08.05.49.333156000 AM 

-----RESULT OF MT0's ANSWER------------
USER | ACCOUNT | OPEN_TIME                         | CLOSE_TIME                       | DURATION
MYUSER | 738152| 16-DEC-2015 07.44.11.168721168721 | 16-DEC-2015 08.05.49.333156333156| +000000000 00:21:38.164435  
MYUSER | 738056| 16-DEC-2015 07.47.28.825647825647 | 16-DEC-2015 08.05.49.333156333156| +000000000 00:18:20.507509  
MYUSER | 738152| 16-DEC-2015 08.06.07.702045702045 | 16-DEC-2015 08.14.49.313336313336| +000000000 00:08:41.611291  
MYUSER | 738056| 16-DEC-2015 08.14.27.239780239780 | 16-DEC-2015 08.14.49.313336313336| +000000000 00:00:22.073556
```

Note how the times associated with 738056 are used to close both accounts, but the 738152 closing event (it is left open the second time) is not addressed at all. I feel this is much closer to what I'm looking for, but still not there yet.

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples of what you expect the input/output to look like?

Comment: Let me play manager for a moment. You want to rewrite this app. To what purpose? What will this gain you? How does this not violate the adage "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"? Thanks.

Comment: This is a request for logging where logging doesn't exist in a core business application which cannot run on anything later than WinXP or Server 2003.   The .Net app is something that mutated from an Access VBA script from the late 1990's and resources for modernization are not available (management is resistant to the change).  Too many hands have been in that code and minor changes cause bugs everywhere. The goal is to provide previously unavailable business metrics for use by members of management to improve performance within their departments. Requirements, including schema, are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE LOG ( UserID, Code, Account, Time ) AS
          SELECT 'MYUSER', 0, 738056, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 08:14:27.239780000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 0, 738152, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 08:06:07.702045000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 0, 738056, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 07:47:28.825647000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 0, 738152, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 07:44:11.168721000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 1, 738056, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 08:14:49.313336000' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 1, 738152, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 08:06:05.657541000' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 'MYUSER', 1, 738056, TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 08:05:49.333156000' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT UserID,
       Account,
       TO_CHAR( Open_Time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS.FFFF' ) AS Open_Time,
       TO_CHAR( Close_Time, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SS.FFFF' ) AS Close_Time,
       TO_CHAR( Close_Time - Open_Time, 'HH24.MI.SS.FFFFFF' ) AS Duration
FROM   (
  SELECT UserID,
         Account,
         Code,
         Time AS Open_Time,
         LEAD( CASE CODE WHEN 1 THEN TIME END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY UserID, Account ORDER BY Time ) AS Close_Time
  FROM   Log
  WHERE  CODE IN ( 0, 1 )
)
WHERE CODE = 0;
```

**Results**:

```
USERID    ACCOUNT OPEN_TIME                                        CLOSE_TIME                                       DURATION                     
------ ---------- ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------
MYUSER     738056 16-DEC-2015 07.47.28.825647000825647000          16-DEC-2015 08.05.49.333156000333156000          +000000000 00:18:20.507509000  
MYUSER     738056 16-DEC-2015 08.14.27.239780000239780000          16-DEC-2015 08.14.49.313336000313336000          +000000000 00:00:22.073556000  
MYUSER     738152 16-DEC-2015 07.44.11.168721000168721000          16-DEC-2015 08.06.05.657541000657541000          +000000000 00:21:54.488820000  
MYUSER     738152 16-DEC-2015 08.06.07.702045000702045000
```

Comment: VERY close, but not quite there.   I'll post the result of this query as an edit, alongside the relevant data.

Comment: I knew I was missing a simple change!  Thank you!